# Objective C While Loop not Looping

Tags: objective-c, while-loop

I have a while loop that should be looping through a condition, but fails to go through the process more than once.

Here is my relevant code:

```
NSInteger i = 0;
    while(i <= building.departments.count)
    {
        NSLog(@"Number of building departments: %lu", (unsigned long)building.departments.count);
        NSLog(@"i : %ld", (long)i);

        UILabel *dtitleLB = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, y, 310, 20)];
        dtitleLB.text = ((DBDepartment*)[building.departments objectAtIndex:i]).Name;
        dtitleLB.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentLeft;
        dtitleLB.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        dtitleLB.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        dtitleLB.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:(16.0)];
        [scrollView addSubview:dtitleLB];
        y += 30;

        UIButton* dphoneNB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [dphoneNB setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
        [dphoneNB setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dphoneNB addTarget:self action:@selector(numberPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [dphoneNB setTitle:((DBDepartment*)[building.departments objectAtIndex:i]).Phone forState:UIControlStateNormal]; i++;
        dphoneNB.frame = CGRectMake(5, y, 315, 25);
        [scrollView addSubview:dphoneNB];
        y += 30;

        UIButton* dwebsiteNB = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [dwebsiteNB setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
        [dwebsiteNB setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.3 green:0.3 blue:0.9 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [dwebsiteNB addTarget:self action:@selector(linkPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [dwebsiteNB setTitle:((DBDepartment*)[self->building.departments objectAtIndex:i - 1]).Website forState:UIControlStateNormal]; i++;
        dwebsiteNB.frame = CGRectMake(5, y, 315, 25);
        [scrollView addSubview:dwebsiteNB];
        y += 30;

        i++;
    }
```

The output for the first NSLog = 1 or greater depending on the user selection (never 0).
The output for the second NSLog = 0 and never gets larger.

If you could go over my code and see if there are any obvious errors, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `building.departments.count` equal to 0 or 1?  You also seem to be incrementing `i` in several places.

Comment: aso the output for the 2 NSLog's at the top would be nice

Comment: how many departments do you have?

Comment: @DavidStarkey `building.departments.count` is equal to 1 or greater (never 0) depending on the user selection. Where else am I incrementing `i` other than the `i++;` at the end of the method?

Comment: Check the end of your lines.  Some are `forState:UIControlStateNormal]; i++;`

Comment: @DavidStarkey Thank you SO much for pointing that out, that may be the reason for all my problems here.

Comment: @VonKoob I've made an answer for you so the question can be considered "Answered"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is not looping (or looping erratically) is because you increment `i` in more than one spot.  See the lines below (broken up to see it easier).

```
...
        [dphoneNB setTitle:((DBDepartment*)[building.departments 
        objectAtIndex:i]).Phone forState:UIControlStateNormal]; i++;
...
        [dwebsiteNB setTitle:((DBDepartment*)[self->building.departments 
        objectAtIndex:i - 1]).Website forState:UIControlStateNormal]; i++;
...
        i++;
```

As an alternative to `while` loops like this, a `for` loop should suffice.

Comment: Thank you so much for noticing my mistake there, you identified the error completely!

Comment: Sometimes a second set of eyes makes all the difference :)

Comment: @VonKoob The original code is also very inefficient. Why extract the `Department` object over and over? Get it once at the top of the loop and store it in a variable. Better yet, use `for (DBDepartment *dept in building.departments)` instead of the `while` loop.